# How to read Google Maps JSON files into Android Studio(Java)

Tags: java, android, json

We are working with Google Maps API for a APP we are making in Android Studio. But we ran into a problem with reading JSON files. How do we get access to all the information sent.

JSON File Snippet:

```
"routes" : [
  {
     "bounds" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 56.30786089999999,
           "lng" : 9.167680600000001
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 56.13854869999999,
           "lng" : 8.967453599999999
        }
     },
     "copyrights" : "Kortdata ©2016 Google",
     "legs" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "7,6 km",
              "value" : 7592
           },
```

More of the JSON file:[JOSNFILE](https://gist.github.com/Bongfeldt/8919ce9deb36cc5227f9517650f680bb)

We need to add up all the distance.value to calculate a total distance. So far we only know how to retrieve the first distance. Keep in mind not all values named distance are relevant.

Currently we can do it with a trip from A to B but if we add a waypoint C, we only get the distance from A to B and not from B to C.

Snippet:

```
private void parseJSon(String data) throws JSONException {
    if (data == null)
        return;

    List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
        Route route = new Route();

        JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
        JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
        JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
        JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");
        JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");
        JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");

        route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
        route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
        route.endAddress = jsonLeg.getString("end_address");
        route.startAddress = jsonLeg.getString("start_address");
        route.startLocation = new LatLng(jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lng"));
        route.endLocation = new LatLng(jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lng"));
        route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

        routes.add(route);
    }

    listener.onDirectionFinderSuccess(routes);
}
```

[Andriod Studio Project](https://github.com/hiepxuan2008/GoogleMapDirectionSimple/)

Comment: Have you stepped through in a debugger or added some logging to figure out what the app is doing?  Also I don't see in this code anything that adds up distances.

Comment: You are correct, we don't know what we need to add up. I imagine that we need to use the JSONObject. Like the: JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance"); But we only get the first distance value.

Comment: OK, sounds like you know what you need to do - what's the problem?